# Configure the Sonar analysis to pick up library/includes

Tags: sonarqube

We're analysing arm-altera-eabi-gcc C/C++ code, and the Sonar analysis is not picking up the library includes as they're in a arm-altera-eabi-gcc specific installation area.

How do we configure the Sonar analysis to pick up the library/includes? (We've tried setting sonar.cfamily.library.directories and sonar.cxx.includeDirectories, but that doesn't seem to have worked)

Thanks,

Gerald.

Comment: Can you show `sonar-project.properties` configuration?

Comment: @hrskrs the relevant line is:  

`sonar.cxx.include-directories=/opt/altera/14.1/embedded/ip/altera/hps/altera_hps/hwlib/include/socal,/opt/altera/14.1/embedded/ip/altera/hps/altera_hps/hwlib/include`

Comment: I suggest you modify your question by adding sonar configuration code. Then show also the log file got from running `sonar-runner` in debugging mode with the following command `sonar-runner -X`

Comment: @GeraldYuen, did you find a solution to this problem?